# swift3 で apple music にて再生した曲の履歴を取得したい

Tags: swift, ios

iOSです。

swift で apple music アプリで過去に再生した曲を取得する方法を教えていただきたいです。

再生中の曲を取得する方法はソースコードが色々ありましたのでなんとなく分かったのですが, 再生した曲を一括で取得する方法はわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

MPMediaItemの[lastPlayedDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/1621719-lastplayeddate)プロパティで最後に再生した日時を取得することができます。
MPMediaQuery.songs()ですべての曲を取得して、lastPlayedDatedの順にソートすることで再生した曲をの履歴を得ることができるのではないかと思います。